# Read json load to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, json, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

I want to ingest data from azure cosmos db, I am using the python sdk for connection in databricks.

I want to be able to save my json.load(data) into a pyspark dataframe as I need to save the data in databricks delta lake, how can I read this data to pyspark dataframe. Below is my code and sample data

```json
{
 "appUuid": "aaaa-bbbb-cccc",
 "SystemId": null,
 "city": "Lancaster",
 "state": "NY",
 "zipCode": "140",
 "field1": "others",
 "field2": "others"
}
{
 "appUuid": "bbbb-dddd-eeee",
 "SystemId": null,
 "city": "Alden ",
 "state": "NY",
 "zipCode": "140",
 "field1": "others",
 "field2": "others"
}
```

```py
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient

client = CosmosClient('https://<cosmos_client>.documents.azure.com:443/', credential='AccountKey')
DATABASE_NAME = 'TestDB'
database = client.get_database_client(DATABASE_NAME)
CONTAINER_NAME = 'Test'
container = database.get_container_client(CONTAINER_NAME)

import json
for item in container.query_items(
         query='SELECT Top 10 * FROM Test',
        enable_cross_partition_query=True):
    data = json.dumps(item, indent=True)
    print(data)
    print(type(data))

# converting string to json dict
data1 = json.loads(data)
print(data1)
print(type(data1))


from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Row
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.json(data1) -- I am getting error on this line.
display(df)
```

I am getting this error:

```
"IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: {"
```

Comment: the error came from which line?

Comment: the  error can from this line df = spark.read.json(data1)
I can read the data into a pyspark dataframe

Comment: @gregeal - please *edit your question* with such details, instead of placing them in comments. Also: what, exactly, is being passed to `spark.read.json()` -isn't the paramter supposed to be a file name and not data? I would suggest spending a bit more time in this area.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, please how do I save my json.dumps as a json file in databricks file system(dbfs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly parse your JSON data

```
data = """{
 "appUuid": "aaaa-bbbb-cccc",
 "SystemId": null,
 "city": "Lancaster",
 "state": "NY",
 "zipCode": "140",
 "field1": "others",
 "field2": "others"
}
{
 "appUuid": "bbbb-dddd-eeee",
 "SystemId": null,
 "city": "Alden ",
 "state": "NY",
 "zipCode": "140",
 "field1": "others",
 "field2": "others"
}"""

import re  
#convert null for parsing
data = re.findall('[^}]+}',data.replace("null",'"null"'))

#cast to dict type
import ast
data = list(map(ast.literal_eval,data))

df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(data))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------------+---------+------+------+-----+-------+
|SystemId|       appUuid|     city|field1|field2|state|zipCode|
+--------+--------------+---------+------+------+-----+-------+
|    null|aaaa-bbbb-cccc|Lancaster|others|others|   NY|    140|
|    null|bbbb-dddd-eeee|   Alden |others|others|   NY|    140|
+--------+--------------+---------+------+------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Yefet, I was able to modify the code to read the json file 
df = spark.read.option("multiline", True).json("/tmp/data.json")
However, when run display(df), I only see one record. How can I display all records please?

Comment: @gregeal i will edit my question explain why

Comment: I am pulling data from a database and can't change the correct the JSON format in the source, how do I convert it through json.loads to array so that I can parse it? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to specify JSON string as a path to data - it doesn't work that way. `.json()` function either accepts file path, or RDD of strings.  To create RDD use following code:

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([data1])
df = spark.read.json(rdd)
```